# Can ffmpeg copy metadata/ID3 from FLAC to MP3?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have  a bit of Python code that loops through audio files, finds .FLAC files, and then uses the Python subcommand to run ffmpeg. It works. The audio is fine, but even though I see the metadata in the shell, it doesn't transfer the data to the ID3 tags in the MP3, and I am using the example found in the previous post here. Here's the command:

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -i "' + src + '" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "' + dst + '"'
```

Which works out to:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "source.flac" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "destination.mp3"
```

And here is the log dump:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /home/krypterro/PycharmProjects/mediaman/RipFLAC.py
1 Music Files Found
2019-04-09 14:32:47.758 | INFO     | __main__:main:31 - Start of program
2019-04-09 14:32:48.110 | DEBUG    | __main__:ripmp3:206 - Running Command: ffmpeg -y -i "/home/krypterro/audio/music_in/Visions/01-grimes-laughing_and_not_being_normal.flac" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 192000 "/home/krypterro/audio/music_out/Visions/01-grimes-laughing_and_not_being_normal.mp3"
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, flac, from '/home/krypterro/audio/music_in/Visions/01-grimes-laughing_and_not_being_normal.flac':
  Metadata:
    ARTIST          : Grimes
    TITLE           : Laughing And Not Being Normal
    ALBUM           : Art Angels
    DATE            : 2015
    track           : 1
    GENRE           : Electronic
    disc            : 1
    TOTALDISCS      : 1
    TOTALTRACKS     : 15
    LANGUAGE        : English
    RIP DATE        : 2015-12-12
    RETAIL DATE     : 2015-00-00
    MEDIA           : CD
    ENCODER         : FLAC 1.2.1 -8 -V
    RIPPING TOOL    : EAC 1.0 Beta 3
    RELEASE TYPE    : Retail
    ORGANIZATION    : 4AD
    CATALOG         : CAD3535CD
  Duration: 00:01:47.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 743 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '/home/krypterro/audio/music_out/Visions/01-grimes-laughing_and_not_being_normal.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TPE1            : Grimes
    TIT2            : Laughing And Not Being Normal
    TALB            : Art Angels
    TDRC            : 2015
    TRCK            : 1
    TCON            : Electronic
    TPOS            : 1
    TOTALDISCS      : 1
    TOTALTRACKS     : 15
    TLAN            : English
    RIP DATE        : 2015-12-12
    RETAIL DATE     : 2015-00-00
    MEDIA           : CD
    CATALOG         : CAD3535CD
    RIPPING TOOL    : EAC 1.0 Beta 3
    RELEASE TYPE    : Retail
    ORGANIZATION    : 4AD
    TSSE            : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libmp3lame
size=    2522kB time=00:01:47.52 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s speed=  41x    
video:0kB audio:2521kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.042501%
2019-04-09 14:32:50.811 | INFO     | __main__:main:73 - End of program

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Works for me. How are you verifying that the metadata exists? (The `-map_metadata 0` is superfluous because that is the default.)

Comment: I open the finished MP3 in various audio programs, like VLC (In Linux) and there is no Metadata. I passed it over to Windows, and Windows doesn't see the Metadata either. But it's for sure in the FLAC file, I can see it in the shell when ffmpeg runs, and I am able to pull it with Mutagen.

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Can't duplicate the issue. [Try a new `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).